# regarding ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

The following method is to implement `toString`

```
public String toString() {
return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

How to understand the parameter `this` used by `toString`, what does it stand for here? Besides, why do we need to implement `toString` this way?

Answer (score 1):

[`ReflectionToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) is a utility class used to generate the `String` returned when overriding [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) using the fields of the class instance passed as an argument.

`this` here refers to current instance of the `Object` whose fields are used to generate the returned `String`

The main advantage to using this class is that the `String` does not have to be generated every time fields are added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the keyword `this` keyword is used as a reference to the current object.